# GCP IAP service doesn't find HTTPS proxy on load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to setup IAP with a HTTPS load balancer as per instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto

My backend is gke cluster that has a ingress on port 80 to access http web server.

Frontend is https with a valid certificate.

The traffic is routed without any issues from LB to web server through HTTPS FE, but when I want to enable IAP using command as below:

```
gcloud beta compute backend-services update k8s-be-30324--34c500f0e91c741a --iap=enabled --global
```

It returns the following output:

```
WARNING: IAP only protects requests that go through the Cloud Load Balancer. See the IAP documentation for important security best practices: https://cloud.google.com/iap/
    WARNING: IAP has been enabled for a backend service that does not use HTTPS. Data sent from the Load Balancer to your VM will not be encrypted.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.backend-services.update) There was a problem modifying the resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.iap': ''. Backend service with IAP enabled requires at least one HTTPS proxy.
```

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a workaround is to use the same LB that is created with ingress for kubernetes cluster instead using a custom one. Of course to avoid leaking unauthorized access FE for http must be removed from the LB.